# Facebook graph api friend_list of two apps toguether

Tags: facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I have two Android apps that use facebook friends of the user and their High Scores. (lite version(A) and pro version(B)).

The problem is that i need to import the user´s facebook friend list of players that use A and B version.

When i import the friend_list from (A) i just get the friends of the user that have (A) and it doesn´t take the friends of the user that play (B)

and the same in the opposite case.

Is there a way to sync (A) and (B) friend_list?

Comment: _“Is there a way to sync (A) and (B) friend_list?”_ – you’ll have to do that on your end. But since you only get app-scoped user ids, you will need to have both apps associated with the same business, so that you can match them.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to make a request to the api facebook two different users, asking your friends list? if so, something like you might be useful...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/friends?ids={user-id-a},{user-id-b}&access_token=*
```

Check documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/